# Matching nested elements with wildcard

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to delete parts of a string with regex. I want to delete all parts, which look like this:

`[[File: bla bla bla]]`

so I used the following regular expression (note: [\x5B] is '[' and [\x5D] is ']'):

```
@"[\x5B][\x5B]File(.*?)[\x5D][\x5D]"
// Translates to @"[[File(.*?)]]"
```

However the text in the file tag can contain further tags, i.e.

`[[File: bla bla [[foo]] bla]]`

The above expression would leave

`bla]]`

because it detects the closing parentheses as the end of the match (note, I am searching non-greedy).

I therefore came up with this:

```
@"[\x5B][\x5B]File(.*?)[\x5B][\x5B](.*?)[\x5D][\x5D](.*?)[\x5D][\x5D]"
// Translates to @"[[File(.*?)[[(.*?)]](.*?)]]"
```

which deletes all File tags, containing one inner tag. First calling this regex and then the simpler one above would delete all with one and zero inner tags.

However, the File tag can contain an arbitrary number of inner tags and obviously, my approach isn't very nice. I am just getting started with regex and any help is much appreciated.

Comment: So you want to delete the entire block of all nested square brackets? Search for `Dot-Net balanced groups`.

Comment: Exactly. The whole thing, no matter how many inner tags...

Comment: They are not nested deeper though, no inner tags containing inner tags...

Comment: I'd suggest, for the purpose of making your problem easier to understand and reason about, replacing your character escape sequences w/ the actual characters.  You can sub the sequences back in on your end once you get a solution.  $0.02.  But this is like parsing HTML with RegEx, very difficult if not impossible to catch all edge cases.

Comment: Added the human readable version in comments ;)

Comment: @Madbreaks: Ok I thought this was kind of easy for regex. But I have no feeling on what regex is good for. All I know so far is that regex is the least readable code I've ever dealt with...

Comment: @Madbreaks - You could use [RegexFormat4](http://www.regexformat.com) to parse and format regex's. It makes life easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is how it is in the books.
`@"\[(?>(?:(?!\[|\]).)+|\[(?<Depth>)|\](?<-Depth>))*(?(Depth)(?!))\]"`

```
 \[                            # Match opening [
 (?>                           # Then either match (possessively):
      (?:                           #  the following group which matches
           (?! \[ | \] )                 #  (but only if we're not at the start of [ or ] )
           .                             #  any character
      )+                            #  once or more
   |                              # or
      \[                            #  [ (and increase the braces counter)
      (?<Depth> )
   |                              # or
      \]                            #  ] (and decrease the braces counter).
      (?<-Depth> )
 )*                            # Repeat as needed.
 (?(Depth)                     # Assert that the braces counter is at zero.
      (?!)                          # Fail this part if depth > 0
 )
 \]                            # Then match a closing ].
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've tried it and it seems to point in the right direction, it only deletes too much. My document is rather short after replacing ;) I think, I'll use a different method than regex here. If I use this approach, there is no chance of ever modifying this again ;)